# not working in the following url?

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {        

        $scope.getlogin = function(){
            $http.get("api/business/getlogin/"+$scope.login.user+"/"+$scope.login.password)
            .success(function(data){
                if(data.length != 0){

                    /*templateUrl: 'new.html'
                    controller:'NewCtrl'*/

                    $window.location.href ='new.html'
                    alert("user foubd")
                }
                else
                    alert("user not found")
            })
        };
}]);
```

Comment: Please take a look at how [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) works..!

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Are you using ngRoute or uiRouter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use "window.location.href" instead of "$window.location.href"

Just remove the $